# SqlServer CE 4.0 commit too slow

Tags: database, performance, sql-server-ce, commit

I have detected an issue with SqlCE 4.0 (it also happened with 3.5) when committing transactions... it's taking a long time to complete!!

The tested transactions are not big (200 new rows), but it's taking a lot of time to commit them: 150ms, 230ms. This commit takes 0ms for other backends like sqlite, firebird or sqlserver.

Any idea about this behavior?

Regards,
    Rubén.